# Spring RetryTemplate return usage

Tags: java, spring, spring-retry, retrytemplate

For example I've a Spring RetryTemplate configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableRetry
public class RetryTemplateConfig {

    @Bean
    public RetryTemplate retryTemplate() {
        SimpleRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
        retryPolicy.setMaxAttempts(5);
        FixedBackOffPolicy backOffPolicy = new FixedBackOffPolicy();
        backOffPolicy.setBackOffPeriod(300000);
        RetryTemplate template = new RetryTemplate();
        template.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);
        template.setBackOffPolicy(backOffPolicy);
        return template;
    }
}
```

And I want to re-invoke this method if exception was caught:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${schedule.cron.update}")
    public void calculate() throws Exception {
        log.info("Scheduled started");
        try {
            retryTemplate.execute(retryContext -> {
                myService.work();
                return true;
            });
        } catch (IOException | TemplateException e) {
            log.error(e.toString());
        }
        log.info("Scheduled finished");
    }
```

So, my method work() in service class can throw exceptions:

```
 public void send() throws IOException, TemplateException {
        ...
    }
```

Seems like it works okay, but I really don't understand what does next code mean:

```
retryTemplate.execute(retryContext -> {
                myService.work();
                return true;
            });
```

Why I can return `true`, `null`, `new Object()` and other stuff? What it affects and where will it be used? What should i return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RetryTemplate executes [RetryCallback](https://docs.spring.io/spring-retry/docs/api/current/org/springframework/retry/RetryCallback.html) which is generic and can return any return type you define.

If you need to get data from successful execution you can return it in callback and get it later in flow

> Returns:
> the result of the successful operation.

[Example](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate&method=execute) of reading file with retry:

> ```
>   return template.execute(context -> {
>       FileUtils.copyURLToFile(new URL(path), copy);
>       return FileUtils.readFileToString(copy, Charset.defaultCharset());
> ```

Comment: Btw, should I catch `Exception` which thrown by `execute` method?

Comment: @hsadik usually you want exception to be thrown to trigger the retry mechanism